# React - Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack

When I try and run webpack in my React application I get 
[image]

I get this error 58 times for different variables. 
I tried removing the @types directory and I get the following error:
[image]

How can this be fixed without adding @types/react back into the project, since that was causing the 58 errors before?

I also tried changing all the 'SVGProps' to a different name 'SVGPropss' inside @types/react/index.d.ts and had no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can this be fixed without adding @types/react back into the project, since that was causing the 58 errors before?

Instead of deleteing `@types/react` delete the *other* definitions of react which are causing the conflict.

## More

Mostly likely the duplicate file will be called `react.d.ts` or `react/index.d.ts`

Comment: Unfortunately, removing the react/index.d.ts resulted in the first error disappearing and the second error remaining

Answer (score 8):

One possibility is that you have other dependencies which either depend on an older version of `@types/react` or yarn/npm has decided they should be using an older version.

For example: `@types/react-dom` depends on `@types/react`. When I encountered this problem, I had just manually changed the version number for `@types/react` and rerun `yarn install`. Yarn happily installed the new version of `@types/react` to my `node_modules/@types/` directory, but it also installed the version I *was* using to all the other modules which depended on `@types/react`. So I ended up with a directory tree like

```
node_modules
+-- @types
|   +-- react // 16.0.2
|   +-- react-dom
|   |   |   +-- node_modules
|   |   |   +-- @types
|   |   |   |   +-- react // 15.0.35
```

You can quickly scan your `./node_modules/@types/` directories and see if they themselves have a sub-directory of `node_modules/@types/react`. If so, this is likely where you duplicate resides.

The way I fixed this was to run

```
> yarn outdated
> yarn upgrade
```

[outdated](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/outdated/) | [upgrade](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/upgrade/)

or

```
> npm outdated
> npm upgrade
```

[outdated](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/outdated) | [upgrade](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update)

If you do not actually wish to upgrade all of the modules output by `outdated` you can give only the modules you want to update as arguments to `upgrade`.
I suspect you could simply run

```
yarn upgrade @types/react
```

and fix the problem completely but I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 4):

You can see all versions of react/react-dom and @types/react/@types/react-dom that are installed using `yarn list --pattern "react"`.

For me, it looked like:

`yarn list v1.3.2
├─ @jupyterlab/apputils@0.15.5
│  ├─ @types/react@16.0.41
│  ├─ react-dom@16.0.0
│  └─ react@16.0.0
├─ @jupyterlab/cells@0.15.4
│  └─ react@16.0.0
├─ @types/react-dom@16.0.3
│  └─ @types/react@16.3.5
├─ @types/react@16.0.34
├─ mdi-react@2.1.19
├─ react-chart-editor@0.11.1
├─ react-color@2.14.0
├─ react-colorscales@0.4.3
├─ react-dom@16.2.0
├─ react-input-autosize@2.2.1
├─ react-plotly.js@1.7.0
├─ react-rangeslider@2.2.0
├─ react-select@1.2.1
├─ react-tabs@2.2.1
├─ react@16.2.0
└─ reactcss@1.2.3`

You can use  yarn's [resolutions](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) feature to resolve specific dependencies to the same version. Add the following to your package.json:

`"resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "16.0.34",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.0.3",
    "react": "~16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.2.0"
  }`

This resolved the "Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type
" error for me.